# Change anchors/Constraints when a button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, subview

I have added a subview inside of a UIViewController. This subview (called PlayerView) should have two states. One is a collapsed state, which only has a height of 56. It's expanded state has a height of 385. When the subview is changed from collapsed to expanded, I want the subviews within the PlayerView to change shape and position.

When the PlayerView is added to the UIViewController (MasterViewController), it uses layoutSubviews() like so:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 24/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1)

    roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10)


    addSubview(albumImage)
    addSubview(songTitleLabel)
    addSubview(songArtistLabel)
    addSubview(playPauseButton)

    _ = albumImage.anchor(nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 40, heightConstant: 40)
    albumImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    _ = playPauseButton.anchor(nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 30, widthConstant: 22, heightConstant: 22)
    _ = songTitleLabel.anchor(albumImage.topAnchor, left: albumImage.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: playPauseButton.leftAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: songTitleLabel.frame.width, heightConstant: songTitleLabel.frame.height)
    _ = songArtistLabel.anchor(songTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: songTitleLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: playPauseButton.leftAnchor, topConstant: 2, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: songArtistLabel.frame.width, heightConstant: songArtistLabel.frame.height)
    playPauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

When the collapsed view is pressed, it is supposed to expand. Here is how I went about doing that (This is inside my MasterViewController):

```
let pv = PlayerView()

func expandPlayerView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.pv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat((self.view.frame.maxY) - 352), width: 375, height: 350)
        self.pv.changePlayerView()

        self.view.layoutSubviews()
    }) { (true) in

    }
}
```

The `changePlayerView()` function is defined like this:

```
func changePlayerView() {
    subviews.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
    addSubview(playPauseButton)
    playPauseButton.removeConstraints(playPauseButton.constraints)        

    _ = playPauseButton.anchor(nil, left: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 22, heightConstant: 22)
    playPauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true        
}
```

What happens after all of this code is executed is:
1. The playerView expands to 385 fine
2. All other subviews are removed from the playerView
3. The play pause button takes up almost the entire `PlayerView` subview, and does not conform to its width and height constraint of 22

What do I need to do to get the playPauseButton conform to all of its constraints?

EDIT:

The `.anchor` function is defined in an extension of UIView like so:

```
func anchor(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    if let top = top{
        anchors.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant))
    }
    if let left = left{
        anchors.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant))
    }
    if let bottom = bottom{
        anchors.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant))
    }
    if let right = right{
        anchors.append(rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant))
    }
    if widthConstant > 0{
        anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
    }
    if heightConstant > 0{
        anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
    }
    anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})
    return anchors
}
```

Comment: I'm having a difficult time going through your code - probably just a coding style difference. BUT - I'm seeing **no** defined or named constraints *nor* any activating/deactivating of existing constraint arrays. Those are the two usual ways to **change** constraints *after* they've been defined. Am I missing something? In other words, stripping things down to a *single* constraint you wish to change - say height or width, how (and maybe when) are you trying to change it?

Comment: Look at the bottom function ‘anchor’. That is how I’m setting up the constraints

Comment: I did. Still having a difficult time. What *specifically* are you trying to do? What *specifically* is the issue? And again, what is changing? (Even better, can you give me something I can actually reproduce? EDIT: I've set up constraints that change. Sliding menus, orientation changes, etc. Nothing in your code posted makes sense! I **get** that your `anchor` function sets, well, *everything* as `isActive = true`. That simply doesn't jibe with your question title - "Changing constraints when a button is pressed".

Comment: The issue is, that when I change the constraints (by running changePlayerView), the playPauseButton button is NOT 22x22. It takes up the entire playerView, which is 375x385. Can you tell the reason of this by the code I have given you? I can give more code if needed

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what is happening in your code, but you are trying to change constraints very differently than I do. Here's what I tend to do for changing constraints:

- Declare all *consistant* or *global* constraints - those that will not change "as usual", setting `isActive = true`. No need to re-write things.
- Explicitly set up those constraints that change, either one at a time or in an array, depending on your needs.
- Never use `removeConstraints`! (While it's maybe more of a personal rule, I've never found a good use case for using it.) Instead set `isActive` or use `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate` and `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` for your arrays.
- Unless you have a specific need to, *do not* remove subviews! Messing with the view hierarchy risks ending up with either missing or incomplete constraints. Instead, use `isHidden = true`.

I'm thinking it's my last bullet point that's the cause for your result.

Here's an example of setting up two arrays of constraints, one for portrait and one for landscape orientation. Say I have two views that I wish to be above each other in portrait but next to each other in landscape.

In my view controller I have two views:

```
var p = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var l = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false

var greenView = UIView()
var redView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    view.addSubview(greenView)
    view.addSubview(redView)

    setupConstraints()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        view.setOrientation(p, l)
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            view.setOrientation(p, l)
        }
    }
}
```

I create two extensions. Here's the view controller extension:

```
extension ViewController {
    func setupConstraints() {

        // create generic layout guides

        let layoutGuideTop = UILayoutGuide()
        view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideTop)

        let layoutGuideBottom = UILayoutGuide()
        view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideBottom)

        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        view.addLayoutGuide(margins)

        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
            layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        } else {
            layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        p.append(greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideTop.topAnchor))
        p.append(greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor))
        p.append(greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor))
        p.append(greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.heightAnchor))

        p.append(redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor))
        p.append(redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor))
        p.append(redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor))
        p.append(redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor))

        l.append(greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideTop.topAnchor))
        l.append(greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor))
        l.append(greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.widthAnchor))
        l.append(greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor))

        l.append(redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideTop.topAnchor))
        l.append(redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.trailingAnchor))
        l.append(redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor))
        l.append(redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:margins.trailingAnchor))
    }
}
```

The real magic is in a `UIView` extension, where I activate/deactivate the two arrays:

```
extension UIView {
    public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    public func setOrientation(_ p:[NSLayoutConstraint], _ l:[NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
        if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
        }
    }
}
```

The other way I change constraints is by directly declaring something and changing the multiplier, constant, or priority. The main trick is to remember you need to separate setting the `isActive` flag. (Don't ask me why. It's improperly typed in Xcode and I'll bet Apple calls it a "behavior".)

```
var myButtonWidth = myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
myButtonWidth.isActive = true
```

And to change is, just code against it:

```
func changeMyButton() {
    myButtonWidth.constant = 200
}
```

Hopefully some of this helps.

Comment: Where do you declare the `myButtonWidth` var? It won't let me declare it outside of a function so how could I change it if it is only available in the function which it is declared (`viewDidLoad()` for example)

Comment: Declare it at a "wider" scope than inside a function. I generally call it at the class level, since constraints tend to be about a view that exists at that level also. In my example, `myButton` is a view available (if needed) to any function in a `UIViewController` class, right? So treat the constraint in exactly the same way. I've actually used constraints in a Framework target by passing them like I would any parameter in and out of a function.